# How to show only the most recent result in a date AND the results in other dates too? SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I'm trying to make a SQL query to bring all the results in a selected period of time, but if there is 2 or more results of the same person on the same date, show only the older.

a brief example:

1. cd_devedor = code of the client (int)
2. dt_ocorrencia = date of the register (datetime)
3. cd_historico = code of the register (int)

```sql
DECLARE @DATA1 AS DATETIME
SELECT @DATA1 = INFORMAR(INFORME DATA INICIAL,H,{DIA/HORA INICIAL})
DECLARE @DATA2 AS DATETIME
SELECT @DATA2 = INFORMAR(INFORME DATA FINAL,H,{DIA/HORA FINAL})

select Oco.CD_Credor, Dev.CD_devedor, r.Dt_Ocorrencia as Data, Oco.Cd_Historico,
from (
    SELECT cd_devedor, MAX(dt_ocorrencia) as dt_ocorrencia
    FROM OCORRENCIA
    group by cd_devedor
)r
inner join ocorrencia oco on oco.cd_devedor = r.cd_devedor and oco.dt_ocorrencia = r.dt_ocorrencia
inner join Devedor Dev on (Oco.Cd_Devedor = Dev.Cd_Devedor)
inner join Historico His on (Oco.Cd_Historico = His.Cd_Historico)
where (oco.Dt_Ocorrencia >= @DATA1) AND (oco.Dt_Ocorrencia <= @DATA2) and oco.cd_devedor = 237
```

This is the code that I have, but it only shows the last result for the client, which isn't what I want.

Comment: Use `MIN()` if you want the oldest match, not `MAX()`

Comment: You probably should move the date filter into the subquery. It's not fully clear how you need the logic to work but if max/min dates falls outside the range then that person will be dropped and I think you don't want that.